# Compact Matplotlib code( define x,y axis together)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I make these lines compact by defining X and Y together in a single line instead of each line for each axis?Thanks,

```
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-4))
ax.xaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True
ax.xaxis.major.formatter._useOffset = False
ax.yaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True
ax.yaxis.major.formatter._useOffset = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be simplified somewhat:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter 
formatter = ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)  
formatter.set_useOffset(False)
f=plt.figure()
ax=f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(range(10), range(10), '.-')
#plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
#plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-4))
#ax.xaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True
#ax.xaxis.major.formatter._useOffset = False
#ax.yaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True
#ax.yaxis.major.formatter._useOffset = False
```

Comment: I should have add a figure but I am still not qualified to do that. So the problem is if I don't define MathText later , the 'sci' has a format like 1e3 instead of x10^3 like you usually get it from matlab and I prefer to publish the figure that way instead of showing 1e3.

Comment: I see, so that means you can't just defined the `formatter` globally once and for all in the beginning.

Comment: Yeah I think 'sci' has a style like 1e3 instead of x10^3. So I still need to add useMathText. Can I protect that option from overwriting? Thanks.